# How @yield becomes value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, yield, sections

I want to use `@yield` like value in blade template. But I have a problem `@yield('key')`:

```
{{ Counter::showAndCount(@yield('key')) }}
```

Could you please help me correct this code.

Comment: I think that you need to see the documentataion how to use templates in laravel `https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates`

Comment: The `@yield` directive is used to display the contents of a given section - I'm not too sure what exactly you're trying to do here, but it looks like you're trying to pass the final rendered HTML into the function `showAndCount`.

Comment: Yeah, `@yield` doesn't work like that. It's a directive used by the Blade templating engine to inject rendered HTML into a master layout. It isn't meant for passing passing values between blade files.

Comment: You can either pass the value to the view or use sessions. You could also make a function in your Counter model and call it from the view. Your approach is not possible because it can't be translated in plain PHP.

Comment: If you add section directive in child layout than @yield become value in master layout.

Answer (score 0):

> the **@yield** directive is used to display the contents of a given
>   section.
>
> The **@section** directive defines a section of content

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

a child page that inherits the layout.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Page Title')


@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```